# Is in boost or stl thread safe containers similar to lists and unordered_maps?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I am using stl and boost containers in program. I added threads so I wonder is in boost or stl thread safe containers similar to lists and unordered_maps ?

Comment: No they're not. Generally speaking, unless explicitly stated, you should consider nothing to be thread-safe. Your life will be much easier that way. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the latest boost release [lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) containers were added.

Answer (score 0):

As of today the Boost's Lockfree framework do not provide thread-safe unordered map or thread safe (and lock free) vector similar to the one you can find in Threadings Building Block API.